# Wire up key to adjust laptop backlight brightness?

Tags: windows-7, brightness, backlight

I threw Windows 7 on a Cr-48, and I'm using the excellent SharpKeys to remap the laptop's F1-F10 keys to do what their little icons look like--such as volume up/down/mute, back/forward in browser, full-screen, etc.  The problem is, as far as I can tell, brightness controls don't have a virtual keycode in Windows, so I can't just remap F6 to VK_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN or something.

I'm willing to write a little widget of my own to get it done.  Does anyone know of a way to programmatically adjust laptop backlight brightness, or an existing utility that might allow me to do what I describe?

Answer (score 0):

There would need to be a driver for the laptop screen that supports it. 
I haven't tried this, but installing a generic laptop driver might work.

You also said you'd like to make a widget for the buttons. I use [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com) to make up hotkeys on my computer. All you have to do is make the script with AutoIt and save it in the Startup folder of your start menu. 
In your case, you'll want to make your script detect key presses for the hotkeys you want that call a Windows API function that sends the brightness up or down command to the driver.

Comment: `There would need to be a driver for the laptop screen that supports it.` Well, it is certainly possible through software *somehow* since Windows detects and show the brightness level changing in the Power Options screen, even when using the `Fn` key combos for screen brightness.